# Expected End of Statement Error When Inserting Formula into Excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting Expected End of Statement Error with the code below. The debugger is highlighting the full stop/period but that is part of the formula.

Can anyone see the issue?

```
Sub ParseSurnames()
    Dim lastRow As Long
   
    'Where is last row of data?
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   
    'Apply formula
    Range("C1:C" & lastRow).Formula = "=IF(A1="","",LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1)-3))"

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to double any quotes within the formula string itself: `Range("C1:C" & lastRow).Formula = "=IF(A1="""","""",LEFT(A1,FIND(""."",A1)-3))"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the code line applying the formula in:

```
Range("C1:C" & lastRow).Formula = "=IF(A1="""","""",LEFT(A1,FIND(""."",A1)-3))"
```

In a string containing ", the double quote must be escaped, using another one. I mean """" for "" and "" for "...

In order to check such strings, please try the next code line:

```
Debug.Print "=IF(A1="""","""",LEFT(A1,FIND(""."",A1)-3))"
```

Does it return in Immediate Window (Ctrl + G, being in VBE) the formula as you need? If yes, this is the way...

Comment: Sorted. Thanks guys